# Need help accessing the access code from URL provided by AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

This is my first project on AWS and I would appreciate it if someone can assist me with the AWS Cognito and google authentication. I am trying to authenticate users using their google email. Once the user's login using a web browser I receive an access token appended to the redirect URI as shown below. I am planning on retrieving the access code and then requesting an access token from AWS Cognito via AWS Lambda to allow users to make various API calls in AWS-Gateway.

I am struggling to extract the access token from the URL.

Redirect URL: https://test.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/?mytoken=

The URL after the user authenticates via google: https://test.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/?mytoken=#id_token=xyzzzzzzzzzzexpires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

Things I already tried:

- Try to access code from URL query parameter in AWS gateway but since the URL contain
  pound sign I am not able to parse or access it as a query parameter
  in AWS lambda.
- Try accessing header in lambda function but access code is not passed
  as a header, it only appends to the path URL

Comment: Please make it more specific. What did you already try? What exactly didn't work? Show us some code with current output and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by using the following steps. The underlying issue was the request-response type.

- Change the OAuth workflow to select 'Authorization code grant' under AWS Cognito > App Client Setting > Oauth 2.0
- AWS Gateway > Resources > Method Response >  Add code 320 and 405
- Change redirect uri to: https://test.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/dev/
- AWS Gateway > Resources > Method Request > Query String Parameter >
  Add 'code'

As I mentioned above the underlying issue was request-responce type. When we request google to response with request type we need to make sure we ask for authentication code and not for authentication token. Here is the google doc for reference:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect